# How do i install Broadcom wireless driver after compile a custom kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling, broadcom, jockey

i have compiled a custom kernel(ck-patchs,ubuntu-patchs) for my netbook, everything workis good, but not wireless, i can't install "Wireless Broadcom STA driver" i got this message :
`Desculpe, a instalação deste driver falhou.`

Por favor, dê uma olhada no arquivo de log para obter detalhes: /var/log/jockey.log

That is saying to i take a look on jockey.log because can't install the driver

so jockey.log :

`http://pastebin.com/PreqBcUs`

Answer (score -1):

I think "ndiswrapper" application can help you more. By this app you can easily install your wifi devices in BC brand.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper